# make: *** No tartgets specified and no makefile found. stop

Tags: makefile, bluez

I was studying about raspberry zero w and BLE communication with python. 
For that work i was trying install bluez. 
But when i trying make command , error with make: *** No tartgets specified and no makefile found. stop.

Searching for sloving this problem, ansers are that in directors makefile dont exist.
But in my case makefile are there.

```
pi@pi:~/bluez-5.41 $ ls
acinclude.m4  client        configure.ac  gobex        Makefile.obexd    peripheral   TODO
aclocal.m4    compile       COPYING       INSTALL      Makefile.plugins  plugins      tools
android       config.guess  COPYING.LIB   install-sh   Makefile.tools    profiles     unit
attrib        config.h.in   depcomp       lib          missing           README
AUTHORS       config.log    doc           ltmain.sh    monitor           src
btio          config.sub    emulator      Makefile.am  NEWS              test
ChangeLog     configure     gdbus         Makefile.in  obexd             test-driver
```

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no Makefile there.

You have instead files named Makefile.am and Makefile.in (and friends).

Looks to me like you need to run Automake on them. Did you consider reading the `INSTALL` instructions? [They're rather informative](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/INSTALL), and available right there in your directory. The `README`'s worth a read, too…

*tl;dr: **reading***

Comment: yes i read INSTALL instructions and i follow the command.
first ./configure was done but next command make dont work..

Comment: Please update your question with _all_ the pertinent information. Exactly what you tried and exactly what the output was.

Comment: If you ran `./configure` then it must have failed.  If it succeeded then you would have a `Makefile` here.  When following directions it's implied that each step must succeed before you can move on to the next step (unless explicitly said otherwise I suppose).  If it failed then _that_ is the question you need to be asking, by providing the command you invoked and the errors you received, etc.

Comment: (Just a note, you do not need to run `automake` here.  Automake converts a `Makefile.am` file into a `Makefile.in` file, and you already have `Makefile.in`.  You just need to run `configure` to convert the `*.in` files.

Comment: THANK you !! I forget check ./configure succedded. thx